# Does body.onload wait for IFrames?

Tags: html, dom, browser, iframe, onload

I know that `onload` event waits for page resources to load before firing - images, stylesheets, etc.

But does this include IFrames inside the page? In other words, is it guaranteed that all the child Frames' `onload`s will always fire before the parent's does?

Also, please let me know if behavior varies between browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see on my pages, each iframe got independent onload, and top-frame onload doesn't wait for iframes to fire.

I got gif/png banners on my site that sometimes loads very slowly, so I put them into iframe and that made whole site and onload event to work faster.

Comment: This is not correct. In most cases the onload event will not fire until all the content in iframes has completed loading. Refer to the following for more information: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/03/using-iframes-sparingly/

Answer (score 7):

No, it doesn't. If you want to do something like that, you'll need to add an onload handler for the iframe. You can do this nicely with jQuery:

```
  <iframe src="http://digg.com"></iframe>
  <script>
    var count = $('iframe').length;
    $(function() {
      // alert('loaded'); // will show you when the regular body loads
      $('iframe').load(function() {
        count--;
        if (count == 0)
            alert('all frames loaded');
      });
    });
  </script>
```

This would alert when all the frames are loaded.

See the example:

http://jsbin.com/azilo

Comment: +1 I need to do this. Thanks for solving my problem (which arose 3 years in the future with respect to this answer ;).

Comment: The example you provide is using the jQuery DOMready event, and not the window.load event. If you modify your example, you will see that the window.load event does not fire until after all content in the iframe has loaded. Refer to the following for more info: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/03/using-iframes-sparingly/

Answer (score 5):

Or plain javascript should work..

```
function checkIframes() {
   if(!i) { i = 0; }
   if(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[i]) {
      document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[i].onload = function () { i++; checkIframes(); }
   }
   else { yourFunctionInHere(); }
}
```

haven't really tested this, but should work... than refer to it with `document.onload = function() { checkIframes(); }`

I don't really like libraries like jQuery, because so far I found I can achieve more with less code, with regular javascript.

Comment: This worked for me, but I needed to add a `setTimeout` on the check function to avoid stack overflow.