# How to get access of <iframe> body using c++/ATL/COM?

Tags: c++, com, iframe, atl, bho

I have written a browser helper object to get the text between the tags and use it for data mining purpose. I tried using it on `igoogle` (basically to test its capability on gadgets) and it failed in some of the cases where an `<iframe>` is present with some external source.

I can get the `<div>` and its child `<iframe>` but fail to get the body.

I get the frame collection from this API `HRESULT IHTMLDocument2::get_frames(IHTMLFramesCollection2 **p);`

The problem can be re-created in igoogle and firefox using the `loan calculator` gadget. You will also need the fire bug extension to debug the page. For reference purpose I am pasting the sample here...

```
<div class="modboxin" id="m_8_b"><div style="border: 0pt none; padding: 0pt; margin: 0pt; width: 100%;" id="remote_8">
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" onload="_ifr_ol(this)" style="border: 0pt none; padding: 0pt; margin: 0pt; width: 100%; height: 100px; overflow: hidden;" name="remote_iframe_8" id="remote_iframe_8" src="http://8.ig.gmodules.com/gadgets/ifr?exp_rpc_js=1&amp;exp_track_js=1&amp;v=682f3db70d7cfff515d7c64fd24923&amp;container=ig&amp;view=default&amp;debug=0&amp;mid=8&amp;lang=en&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nova.edu%2F%7Ewillheat%2Floan.xml&amp;country=US&amp;parent=http://www.google.com&amp;libs=core:core.io:core.iglegacy:auth-refresh&amp;synd=ig&amp;view=default#st=...B27zWVKsnJu6OviCNnzXoPjkDsbPg95yZNMwfmMaLnwWoRxGaRArxTpOqK4TiH87uGUiHnYkkaqU9NE1sOyms6sg/Jwi&amp;gadgetId=116809661812082345195&amp;gadgetOwner=105250506097979753968&amp;gadgetViewer=105250506097979753968&amp;rpctoken=422312139&amp;ifpctok=422312139">
</iframe>
</div>
```

The link is not complete as I have replaced some part of the `src` with `...`. Now as you can see that there is no body for the  although it is getting rendered in the browser..

As per this post ( `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957133/does-body-onload-wait-for-iframes` ) the onload event on body does not wait for frames to complete.

So I can conclude that I have to use some sort `onload` listener for the `<iframe>`... but I am not sure how ...

Kindly suggest a way/snippet to retrieve the body of the `<iframe>` using ATL/COM APIs...

** Update **

I am using the following code to get the `<iframes>`. Although i get the iframe collection but when i try to get their body it fails... may be because they are not loaded by that time ?!

```
void testFrame(IHTMLDocument2* pDocument)
{
    CComQIPtr<IHTMLFramesCollection2> col;
    HRESULT hr = pDocument->get_frames(&col);
    if((hr == S_OK) && (col != NULL))
    {
        long counter = 0;
        hr = col->get_length(&counter);
        if((hr == S_OK) && (counter > 0))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                VARIANT     v1, v2;
                v1.vt = VT_I4; v1.lVal = i;
                VariantClear (&v2);
                hr = col->item(&v1, &v2);

                if (hr == S_OK && (v2.vt == VT_DISPATCH))
                {
                    CComPtr<IDispatch> pDispatch = v2.pdispVal;
                    CComQIPtr<IHTMLWindow2, &IID_IHTMLWindow2> pFrame = pDispatch;

                    if(pFrame)
                    {
                        CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> spHTML;
                        hr = pFrame->get_document (&spHTML);

                        if((hr == S_OK) && (spHTML != NULL))
                        {
                            CComQIPtr<IHTMLElement> elem;
                            hr = spHTML->get_body(&elem);
                            if((hr == S_OK) && (elem != NULL))
                            {
                                CComBSTR str;
                                hr = elem->get_innerHTML(&str);
                                if((hr == S_OK) && (str != NULL))
                                {
                                    box(str);
                                }else if(hr != S_OK) {
                                    box(_T("hr is not ok"));
                                }else if(str == NULL){
                                    box(_T("STR is null"));
                                }else
                                    box(_T("Failed"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And,

```
void box(LPCWSTR msg)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,msg,_T("..BOX.."),MB_OK);
}
```

Any suggestions, how to get the iframe body .... by the way I am handling this in `OnDocumentComplete` event...

Thanks,

Comment: I'm sorry - what is your question exactly?

Comment: Hi Changeling, I am trying to get the body of the <iframe>.. which i am not able to retrieve using the above said API..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of updating my own question.. I am putting this as an answer. Though I would really love to see an alternate answer...

**--Solution--**

My basic assumptions are:

1. I know about the urls to handle..
2. A page can be divided in two main events (there could be other events too but these two will do)

   - The completion of the main page
   - Completion of the `<iframes>`

**Code**

```
void STDMETHODCALLTYPE CSafeMaskBHO::OnDocumentComplete(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *pvarURL)
{
    CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2> spTempWebBrowser = pDisp;

    CComBSTR url = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = spTempWebBrowser->get_LocationURL(&url); // You can also take the url from pvarURL .. 

    if((hr == S_OK) && (url != NULL))
    {
        /*
            I know which url's I am looking for
        */
        if(!(wcsstr(url,_T("www.example.com")) != NULL) && !((wcsstr(url,_T("www.test.com")) != NULL))){
            return;
        }       

        CComPtr<IDispatch> frameDocDisp;
        hr = spTempWebBrowser->get_Document(&frameDocDisp);
        if((hr == S_OK) && (frameDocDisp != NULL))
        {
            CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument3> spHTMLDoc = frameDocDisp;
            // ... Do someting useful ...

        }

    }else if(spTempWebBrowser && m_spWebBrowser && m_spWebBrowser.IsEqualObject(spTempWebBrowser))
    {
        CComPtr<IDispatch> spDispDoc;
        hr = m_spWebBrowser->get_Document(&spDispDoc);

        if ((hr == S_OK) && (spDispDoc != NULL))
        {
            CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument2> spHTMLDoc = spDispDoc;
            if(spHTMLDoc)
            {
                // ... Do someting useful ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you think that you have anything to share (suggestions/corrections/alternatives) then please do so.. :)

Thanks,