# JS function execution order

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I have two pages namely `Parent.xhtml`(controls the layout) and `Child.xhtml`(displays the content). Child page is included in the Parent page by using `<iframe>` tag.

I need to implement an onload functionality by using javascript. Before that, I want to know in which order the javascript functions will execute?

Will the Parent page js function execute first? or Child page js function will execute first?

Awaiting your answers.! Thanks in advance

Comment: Which would you want to run first?  The Parent or Child?

Comment: In my opinion you can't assume a fixed execution order. It will depend on browsers, speed of page loading, etc. You should code your script with the right events of page load.

Comment: i want the parent page script to run first, then the child page script need to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957133/does-body-onload-wait-for-iframes), browsers might not wait for iframes to load before firing the onload event on the parent window. You can't make assumptions on which one will complete first - there's the possibility of a race condition going on there, so either one could finish first.

One solution might be to write a function that waits until it's been called a certain number of times before executing:

```
var runs = 0;
function onLoad() {
    if (++runs < 2) return;
    // put code to execute once both have loaded
}
```

Then in HTML:

```
<body onload="onLoad();">
    .....
    <iframe onload="onLoad();">
```

Alternatively, set the URL of the iframe in the onload handler of the parent window.