# Javascript: iterating over heights of <iframe> returns 0 for some, all have height > 0

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, twitter

I'm programmatically rendering tweets on a webpage.  Twitter's js file causes these tweets to render as `<iframe>`s.  I'm intending to use a javascript function to run once the page is fully loaded, then collect the heights of each respective iframe height into an array, which is used later for adjustment of displays.

I'm currently running these two functions first, to ensure the page is fully loaded before proceeding:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $(window).load(function () {});
    setTweetContainerHeights(document.getElementsByClassName('twitter'), 
        document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'));
};
```

And the simple setTweetContainerHeights function:

```
function setTweetContainerHeights(containers, iframes) {
var iframeHeights = [];
for(var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    iframeHeights.push(iframes[i].offsetHeight);
}
```

Of 20 total tweets displayed on the page, each time at least one of values is 0 despite each tweet existing and displaying on the page with a height > 0.  Is this an **issue** of the **page not fully loading**?  Is there **another reason** some of these element heights are not being returned properly?

Answer (score 1):

sorry for posting as answer since I can't post comments.

Based from various sources on the net,e.g.

- [Does body.onload wait for IFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957133/does-body-onload-wait-for-iframes)
- https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20654228/Does-a-window-onload-event-trigger-after-iframe-fully-loads.html
- http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/03/using-iframes-sparingly/

---

The common understanding is that the main window's onload event does not get fired until all iframes have completely loaded.

However, if these iframes' src are dynamically set, then the setting of the src would happen after the iframes have already been loaded, and thus, after the main window's onload event.

I'am not familiar with twitter's js, but my guess is that the iframes are dynamically generated and added by javascript, rather than being generated on the server side. And thus, did not block the main window's onload event from firing.

The safest thing to do then is to create a function that checks for the height of iframes, then record those with non-zero heights, then repeat the process using setTimeout until all heights are defined.

pseudo code:

```
var iframeheights=[];

function checkHeight(){
  var missing=0;
  $("iframe").each(function(idx){  
    if (iframeheights[idx]) return true;
    var height=$(this).offsetHeight();
    if (height>0) {
      iframeheights[idx]=height;
    } else{
      missing++;
    }
  });
  if (missing) {
    setTimeout(checkHeight, 10);  
  } else { 
    //load completed, do something or call a callback.
  }
}

$(function(){
  checkHeight();
});



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

});
});